# Is there a pitch maneuver in launch vehicle trajectory to raise the perigee altitude in order to circularize?

Tags: launch-trajectories

What is the purpose of the pitch manoeuvre that is being executed here in the following Vega launch video?

https://www.youtube.com/embed/kbq-LTDzSLM?start=459&end=507

Similar manoeuvre in the following Antares launch video as well:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/NfpVbh2ID00?start=472&end=545

Is it for raising the perigee of the orbit i.e. to circularize the trajectory or some other purpose?

What are the trajectory manoeuvres available for circularizing the multi-stage launch vehicle trajectory?

Answer (score 5):

You can think about it (approximately) by dividing the rocket trajectory into "up" and "downrange" parts.  The "downrange" part is the largest one: To get to orbit, the rocket has to generate a lot of speed in that direction.

The "up" part is quite different.  To end up in a low, circular orbit, the rocket has to go "up" few hundred kilometers and *stop*.

If you just treat this a parabolic motion, "I'll build up some vertical speed and coast up until gravity stops me", that's fine for a high orbit:  You blast out of the atmosphere and eventually stop at the right height.  But it's not great if your orbit is a low one:  To keep the vertical speed low enough (still fast, but comparatively slower than the first example), you spend a lot of time in the first part, still in the atmosphere.  And that causes drag losses and heating you don't want.

So the first part of the flight builds up a lot of vertical speed to get you out fast.  Now you're got too much vertical speed to end up in the right circular orbit, so later in flight you add a downwards component to the thrust so that you arrive at the right final altitude and stop.